# Time-series forecasting - how to use the saved model to predict future data?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, time-series, recurrent-neural-network

I would like to make time series forecasting according to the wonderful tutorial below.

https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/23_Time-Series-Prediction.ipynb

With the data I have, training is going well.

What I want is to predict the data for unseen **future 24 hours (2022-06-06)** when I put past data (from `2022-05-21 00:00` to `2022-06-05 24:00`) into the model.

What should I do?

Below grey line is the original input signals `2022-05-21 00:00` to `2022-06-05 24:00`.

And red line is from `y_pred = model.predict(past_dataset)`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to predict the values one by one and add the prediction to your next inputs.

**Suppose that :**

With inputs = [X(t-n), X(t-n+1), ...., X(t)], your model predict X(t+1)
And that you want the predict X(t+24)

Then you need to predict the values one by one, and use your prediction to predict the next value.

1. **First step :**
   *[X(t-n), X(t-n+1), ...., X(t)] --> **X(t+1)***
2. **Second step :**
   *[X(t-n+1), X(t-n+2), ...., **X(t+1)]** --> X(t+2)*

....

24. **Last step  :**
    *[X(t-n+23), X(t-n+24), ...., X(t+23)] --> **X(t+24)***

Then you predicted your desired value.

By the way, this solution works if you do not want to change your model, but your predictions will suffer from noises and inaccuracies due to the repeated predictions. To me, the best solution is simply to train your model to predict the t+24 value directly. So that your model act like this : *[X(t-n), X(t-n+1), ...., X(t)] --> **X(t+24)***